# wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) in sunspots

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Controller:

```
   def index
     @search = Onj.search do
        fulltext params [:search]
     end
     @onjs = @search.results
     logger.debug params
   end
```

index.html.erb:

```
 <%= form_tag onj_index_path, :method => :get do %>
     <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
   <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
   </p>
  <% end %>
```

Error is:

```
ArgumentError in OnjController#index
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
" def index
@search = Onj.search do
fulltext params [:search]
end
@onjs = @search.results "
```

Comment: On which line? Btw, I would strongly recommend writing the `fulltext` line as either `fulltext params[:search]` at a minimum. I'm personally not a huge fan of omitting function call parens except in very DSL-ish contexts, but that's often a separate issue. Also, if you're only using the search results on the page, I'd probably not have `search` be an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space in `params [:search]` on line 3 in index method.